# I am plotting a 3d plot and i want the colours to be less 'distinct'

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

My code can be seen here:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

xlist = [+30,+20,+10,0,-10,-20,-30]
ylist = [0.0008,0.0009, 0.001, 0.0012, 0.0013]  
total_costs=[[2084.8771849999903, 17314.19051000003, 26026.73173, 65340.709810000015, 108130.0746, 143560.64033000002, 188387.24033], [2129.155209999997, 17314.301310000024, 26026.996729999984, 65341.17821, 108130.792, 143561.44293000002, 188388.11793], [6637.1766100000095, 17314.412110000034, 26027.26173, 65341.646609999996, 108131.5094, 143562.24553000001, 188388.99553], [6623.21941000002, 17314.63371000004, 26027.791729999997, 65342.58341000001, 108132.9442, 150322.81264000002, 191661.16901], [6637.240810000003, 17314.744510000033, 26028.05673000001, 65343.05181000002, 110971.15911000001, 146393.01711000002, 191661.93621]]

Z = np.array(total_costs)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False,alpha=0.5, 
                        `rstride=1,cstride=1, label='skata')`

ax.set_xlabel('System-1 imbalance')
ax.set_ylabel('Penalization factor [€/MWh]')
ax.set_zlabel('Total balancing costs [€]')
#ax.set_legend('upper left', fontsize=15)
#ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=15)

plt.show()
```

When i run this i get a figure like this:

[image: result]

What i would like is to get a figure like this:

[image: wanted result]

I guess it has something to do with my result being a list within a list with discrete values. Anyone got an idea?
Thank you in advance

Comment: "Something like this" is not a good problem description. Which feature of the one plot would you like to have in the other plot?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am sorry! The colors in my plot are really separate into 7 different areas, which is the 7 lists of my total_costs. I would like those colors to be more mixed and less 'organised', if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want a more gradual tone change on the graph - the way I know how to do it is to "simply" increase the number of points being plotted using interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
import scipy.interpolate as interp


xlist = np.array([+30, +20, +10, 0, -10, -20, -30])
ylist = np.array([0.0008, 0.0009, 0.001, 0.0012, 0.0013])
total_costs = [[2084.8771849999903, 17314.19051000003, 26026.73173,
                65340.709810000015, 108130.0746, 143560.64033000002,
                188387.24033],
               [2129.155209999997, 17314.301310000024, 26026.996729999984,
                65341.17821, 108130.792, 143561.44293000002, 188388.11793],
               [6637.1766100000095, 17314.412110000034, 26027.26173,
                65341.646609999996, 108131.5094, 143562.24553000001,
                188388.99553],
               [6623.21941000002, 17314.63371000004, 26027.791729999997,
                65342.58341000001, 108132.9442, 150322.81264000002,
                191661.16901],
               [6637.240810000003, 17314.744510000033, 26028.05673000001,
                65343.05181000002, 110971.15911000001, 146393.01711000002,
                191661.93621]]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
Z = np.asarray(total_costs)

Zfunc = interp.interp2d(X, Y, Z, kind='cubic', copy=False)
n_points = 100  # change this to change the "resolution"
xnew = np.linspace(start=min(xlist), stop=max(xlist), num=n_points)
ynew = np.linspace(start=min(ylist), stop=max(ylist), num=n_points)
Xnew, Ynew = np.meshgrid(xnew, ynew)
Znew = Zfunc(xnew, ynew)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8))
ax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.05, 0.9, 0.9], projection='3d')
surface = ax.plot_surface(Xnew, Ynew, Znew, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                          cmap='coolwarm', linewidth=0.25)
fig.colorbar(surface, shrink=0.75, aspect=9)

plt.show()
```

Linear interpolation:
[image: Linear]
Cubic interpolation:
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted!!! Thank you very very much for your help!!! Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The faces of the surface plot are colorized according to the `Z` value.

To get mixed or random colors on the faces you can supply a color array with the `facecolors` argument instead of a colormap.

```
colors=np.random.rand(X.shape[0]-1,X.shape[1]-1, 3)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=colors,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False,alpha=0.5, 
                        rstride=1,cstride=1, label='skata')
```

produces

[image]

In order to make the colors appear more close to each other, the solution would be not to use the complete range of the colormap. E.g. you could set `vmin=0.5*Z.min(), vmax=2*Z.max(),` in your call to `plot_surface` in order to map the colors to a range much larger than the one shown in the image, such that the actual values only cover part of the colormap.

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, vmin=0.5*Z.min(), vmax=2*Z.max(),
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False,alpha=0.5, 
                        rstride=1,cstride=1, label='skata')
```

[image]

Comment: That wasn't what i meant, but it is nice to know :) thanks!! i meant just not to be a separation so 'clear' between the colors, but i guess it's because of my z axis

Comment: The more clearly you describe the problem and desired behaviour the higher the chances someone understands what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that is better than before!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```
def stackQuestion():
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d 
    xlist = np.array([+30,+20,+10,0,-10,-20,-30])
    ylist = np.array([0.0008,0.0009, 0.001, 0.0012, 0.0013])
    total_costs=[[2084.8771849999903, 17314.19051000003, 26026.73173, 65340.709810000015, 108130.0746, 143560.64033000002, 188387.24033], 
                 [2129.155209999997, 17314.301310000024, 26026.996729999984, 65341.17821, 108130.792, 143561.44293000002, 188388.11793], 
                 [6637.1766100000095, 17314.412110000034, 26027.26173, 65341.646609999996, 108131.5094, 143562.24553000001, 188388.99553], 
                 [6623.21941000002, 17314.63371000004, 26027.791729999997, 65342.58341000001, 108132.9442, 150322.81264000002, 191661.16901], 
                 [6637.240810000003, 17314.744510000033, 26028.05673000001, 65343.05181000002, 110971.15911000001, 146393.01711000002, 191661.93621]]

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
    Z = np.array(total_costs) 

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (11, 8))
    ax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.05, 0.9, 0.9], projection = '3d')
    surface = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1,\
        cmap = 'coolwarm', linewidth = 0.25)
    fig.colorbar(surface, shrink = 0.75, aspect = 9)

    plt.show()
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: That is also helpful. What i wanted is to have the colors from the scale in the 3d plot. I just don't like that the colors are so distinct in areas..anyway, thank you very much! I will use that as well

Comment: Beside... I think you may pick a color at the bottom of [this page](http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/matplotlib/), possibly there's a color you like~